# How do I convert the language in perl? (Slack & VisualSVN Server)

Tags: windows, perl, svn, visualsvn-server, slack

slack and are used as the Visualsvn Server. ([Slack & Visualsvn](http://blog.catalystlogic.com.au/?p=56))

But strangely, the letters will appear in the Slack.

[image]

My language is using a korean (Hangul).

How do I convert to the content of my svn.pl ko_KR-UTF8 inde below?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


# Copyright 2013 Tiny Speck, Inc
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.


#
# An SVN post-commit handler for posting to Slack. Setup the channel and get the token
# from your team's services page. Change the options below to reflect your team's settings.
#
# Requires these perl modules:
# HTTP::Request
# LWP::UserAgent
# JSON


# Submits the following post to the slack servers

# POST https: //foo.slack.com/services/hooks/subversion?token=xxxxxx
# Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
# Host: foo.slack.com
# Content-Length: 101
#
# payload=%7B%22revision%22%3A1%2C%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fsvnserver%22%2C%22author%22%3A%22digiguru%22%2C%22log%22%3A%22Log%20info%22%7D

#
# I am not a perl programmer. Beware.
#

use warnings;
use strict;

use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use HTTP::Status qw(is_client_error);
use LWP::UserAgent;
use JSON;

#
# Customizable vars. Set these to the information for your team
#

my $opt_domain = "*************"; # Your team's domain
my $opt_token = "****************"; # The token from your SVN services page


#
# this script gets called by the SVN post-commit handler
# with these args:
#
# [0] path to repo
# [1] revision committed
#
# we need to find out what happened in that revision and then act on it
#

my $log = `svnlook log -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
my $who = `svnlook author -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
my $url = ""; # optionally set this to the url of your internal commit browser. Ex: http://svnserver/wsvn/main/?op=revision&rev=$ARGV[1]
chomp $who;

my $payload = {
    'revision'  => $ARGV[1],
    'url'       => $url,
    'author'    => $who,
    'log'       => $log,
};

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(15);

my $req = POST( "https://${opt_domain}/services/hooks/subversion?token=${opt_token}", ['payload' => encode_json($payload)] );
my $s = $req->as_string;
print STDERR "Request:\n$s\n";

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
$s = $resp->as_string;
print STDERR "Response:\n$s\n";
```

In linux SVN server was used to convert the Hangul through the link below.
( [Perl SVN hook with czech characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156655/perl-svn-hook-with-czech-characters) )

```
use Encode qw(decode_utf8);
...
my $log = qx|export LC_ALL="cs_CZ.UTF-8"; /usr/bin/svnlook log -r $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]|;
$log = decode_utf8($log);
```

In the Windows VisualSVN server how I do need to use the part?

Comment: Use https://github.com/robertmiles3/svn-slack-notifier instead of this Perl script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [SVNSlackNotifier open-source](https://github.com/robertmiles3/svn-slack-notifier) utility for posting commit notifications to Slack. It is listed on the [Community-built Integrations page](https://api.slack.com/community#csharp) of Slack:

> svn-slack-notifier - A simple app to send VisualSVN Server commit
>   notifications to Slack